# Frustrating site, why can't I vote or do anything?

Tags: discussion

I read the tour and all that but I have to say, it's frustrating that  I can't do anything here except ask a question.  I can't vote, I can't even comment.  I feel like I'm wasting my time.  It seems like these rules would just drive people away.

Shouldn't I be able to at least vote or comment as a new user?

What is the danger of that?

Why can't a participate at a minimal level here?

Not trying to be a sour grape but this is just a bit frustrating.

Comment: You can vote now!  Look at all that rep you have.  You can even downvote if you want since you hit 125.  Fly.  Be free.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need 15 rep to be able to vote - for which you'd need to receive two upvotes as a totally new user (starting with 1), or none at all if you're an existing user of another Stack Exchange site (starting with 101). It's simply to make you post something (either a question or an answer) so that we know who you are, and that we know you're a real user - otherwise, as UNIKITTY suggested, someone nefarious could come along and create many accounts to upvote themselves.

As I write this, you're on 44, so you should be able to vote to your heart's content :) Welcome to the site!

Comment: As well, you now have 64 so the world is your oyster.  Welcome indeed!

Comment: I don't know if *to your hearts content* would be correct ... Can vote to their hearts content or until they reach 40 votes in a day, which ever comes first, right? :D

Comment: I suppose if your heart wants 41 votes to use then it won't be content.  @ppoggio thanks for the great questions and answers and contributing to the site!  Welcome again.   More Aprilia questions!    :D