# February and March 2016 Challenges are here!

Tags: discussion, challenges, voting

After talking with several people here on Mechanics.SE, we believe the [January Challenge](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/earn-the-electorate-badge-in-january-2016-and-get) has gone very well. We want to follow it up with new challenges for the February/March time period so as to keep the momentum going.

The new challenge will actually be *challenges*. To play this month, you'll be able to finish out the January Electorate Badge challenge which you may have started in January, but didn't get finished. You'll actually have two months in which to complete the new challenges which we've come up with. Here are all three challenges, their newly assigned points values, and what time frame you'll have to complete them.

- [Electorate](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) = **200 points** - running 1-29 February
- [Research Assistant](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant) = **200 points** - running 1 Feb - 31 Mar
- [Sportsmanship](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) = **100 points** - running 1 Feb - 31 Mar

Earn any or all of these badges during the months listed and I'll spot you the points.

To earn the **Research Assistant** badge, you need to have edited 50 tag wikis. We're looking to see some good information thrown into them! Each edit will go through a review process (normal procedure) by three people (I believe) who can do the reviews. Until it passes the reviews, it is still out in the open. There are plenty of tags to have wikis added to them, so have fun with it!

To earn the **Sportsmanship** badge is a little bit more complicated. You have to upvote 100 answers to questions where you have answered. Your answer must also have a positive score. This requires you to post *good answers* and reward others for their good answers.

All three challenges can be tracked through your badges in your profiles. See how well you are doing and what you need to do to make it happen. If you have any questions about the challenges, please post a comment below, or make sure you hit me up at [*The Pitstop*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), the site's chat room. I can be found in there daily!

Again, I'll be putting up all of the bounty points for you. Make sure you have a worthy answer I can put the points towards! If you complete a challenge and you don't have what I consider a worthy answer, I'll hold the points until you do.

Now, get out there and make things happen!

Comment: Congrats to our first successful challenge completion ... @BobCross !!! You are the man for completing the Sportsmanship badge challenge!

Comment: Congrats to our second successful challenge completion ... @DucatiKiller !!! You, too, are the man! Completing the Sportsmanship badge challenge :D

Comment: And there are 3 challenges I don't qualify for. :D

Comment: Congrats to our third successful challenge completion! ... @Ppoggio for your completion of the Electorate badge challenge! Great job!

Comment: Congrats to our fourth successful challenge completion! ... @PoissonFish for your completion of the Electorate badge challenge! Great job!

Comment: Edit reviews are done by two people.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - Forgive me ... I am not understanding your point? Could you clarify for me, please? Are you saying it takes two people to accept the edit within the edit review queue?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Exactly that. It only takes 3 people on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I want to post up those who completed Challenges in February, so here goes!!

Congrats to our first successful challenge completion ... **@BobCross** !!! You are the man for completing the Sportsmanship badge challenge!

Congrats to our second successful challenge completion ... **@DucatiKiller** !!! You, too, are the man! Completing the Sportsmanship badge challenge :D

Congrats to our third successful challenge completion! ... **@Ppoggio** for your completion of the Electorate badge challenge! Great job!

Congrats to our fourth successful challenge completion! ... **@PoissonFish** for your completion of the Electorate badge challenge! Great job!

Comment: Thanks for rep.  Very generous of you to give out your own rep to get voting in order here.  Very much appreciated.  TY

Comment: @DucatiKiller - My pleasure, Sir.