# Getting Votes Back

Tags: discussion

**If you have enough rep, you will be able to see this.**

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/site-analytics

**Votes peaked at 488 on January 6th after this post from Jon Ericson**

[How can we increase the number of eligible voters?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/how-can-we-increase-the-number-of-eligible-voters)

**General Stats**

Our last peak was 288 votes on March 17th.

So that's a net loss of 200 votes per day.

**Thoughts**

If you look at the site analytic the traffic increased with the additional voting and we picked up about 75 users with over 200 rep in that time period from the beginning of January.  It directly links voting to increased user base and traffic which ultimately fuels questions which, as of right now are 13.1 per day.

I've been struggling a bit because of a drop off of answering of questions, this is just the last few days, and have tried to fill the gap.

We need more mid level users and truly believe the data supports voting as the primary vehicle to rectify this issue.

Interested in hearing peoples thoughts on this.

Comment: Can you flag a post as "awesome"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot agree more with what you're saying here. It is what I've been preaching to *everyone* for a long long time. It's also what Jon Ericson said [in this Meta post](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1447/4152). It is the entire reason why I offer my hard <*cough*> earned <*cough*> points up to *anyone* who has the willingness to vote. I know you know this, Ducati, but just want to make sure it is plain to all.

Bottom line is, let's get out the vote.