# Ok when are we going to graduate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Based on the stats from area51 at this moment we are 1912 days in beta and our stats are very good, well in my opinion:

[image]

You can follow [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair) but that leads me to ask my question.  When are we going to graduate?  Several other sites have graduated with far less days in beta so is there a formula we cannot see that decides that?

Comment: It's not the days in Beta which matter the most. I believe if you hold your britches on, it won't be long. The thing we need is a higher voter base as Jon Ericson wrote in [this Meta Post](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/how-can-we-increase-the-number-of-eligible-voters). Really, I don't think it will be long, but voting is a key to making it happen. Ensure you get all your cronies on board and vote their little digits red! :o)

Comment: I vote every good Q&A I can see.  Well over my silver badge at the moment.

Comment: Glad to hear it! :o)

Comment: Each time you ask a question about when will graduation happen, it postpones the process by one more year >:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing this as it was indicated that we have graduated.

Comment: Indeed we have!  Congratulations to us!

Answer (score 9):

**Great Question**

There has been talk that we need to have a big enough active user base to support an election.  [**They**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) have stated this in chat as well.

The discussion really began on [**December 30th, 2015 in chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/340/2015/12/30) and with [**this post that Jon wrote in our Meta**](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/how-can-we-increase-the-number-of-eligible-voters).

The core issue is, if we don't have enough mid-level active users then the election will fail and the whole site falls into a bit of a hole.  That was at least the concern that the SE employees have as they have seen sites fall apart after getting out of Beta during the election phase.  "Falling into a hole" is my verbiage and not so descriptive but....so {insert issue here}.

What Jon wanted to see was **more voting** to build that mid user base up.  Reward the users and they shall stick is that essential message.  So, [**@Paulster2**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/4152/p%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%9C%CA%9Fs%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%87%CA%802) started to give away rep for badges at that point, notice how most of the monthly challenges have been built around voting?

All of that being storyline being said, we are close.  We need to build the mid-level user base and vote, get users to stick by being nice, help new users by editing their questions and letting them know you have, "hey, I helped out your question and fixed it up a bit, let me know if you think I changed the feel of it too much." type of comment perhaps.  Start the interaction with them, invite them to chat.  Tell a joke.  All in all, we need to pull users and get them to stay, rewarding them with votes does that.

**Graduation**

They say we are close.  I think we are too.  The stats look pretty good but voting is down over the last 6 weeks, a good percentage drop IMO.  I think we need to fire up the message for everyone to vote more.  I would, but I don't have the time these days.  WE will get there.  Hopefully soon.

Feel free to message @jonericson in chat, he will come and answer your questions.  He's a good responsive guy.

Comment: Well said Paul. I know we've all been preaching this for the past several months. I, too, feel we are very close to graduating. Hopefully Jon E. and crew feel we've made enough of a dent and can now get an election going. I think there is enough of a user base and mid-level people to make it happen now. I appreciate all of your time and effort you've put into the site ... it has made a HUGE difference. There aren't many people I can point to on here who have made anywhere close to the difference you've made. I hope it is noted and appreciated by all.