# The tour page is rubbish. Let's fix it

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Could we add some of the close reasons to `Don't ask about` section of the tour page?

As right now it is very generic, simply saying:

> Anything not directly related to motor vehicle maintenance or repair
>
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based
>
> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

We need to encourage more users to stay at the site [to increase our voter population](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/how-can-we-increase-the-number-of-eligible-voters), and if our tour page is vague, how do we expect new users to know what they can and can't ask about?

I feel as if this would be better:

> Don't ask:
>
> Questions seeking price-shopping assistance or "Where can I buy this?" or "How much is this?"
>
> Questions on driving techniques
>
> Questions which are primarily opinion based
>
> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
>
> Many small questions about different things in one large, long question.

I was also thinking about adding something along the lines of `Questions about a specific make and model of car` to the `Do ask about` section, but then that could potentially make generic [engine-theory](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-theory) questions offtopic and stop users from asking it, as some of our most popular questions are generic car questions, and not specific to a make and model

**What do you think? I feel as this is a quick and easy way to reduce the amount of off-topic questions.**

EDIT: Added this as well "Many small questions about different things in one large, long question."

Comment: Why don't you add a `More than one question` one - I don't know how to phrase it, but I've seen people ask three different questions at the same time (in the same post) - Otherwise good idea...

Comment: How about this - Don't ask "Many small questions about different things in one large, long question."?

Comment: Yeah or maybe simplify it by talking about the number of topics

Comment: It would be nice to have some input on my idea instead of just 11 upvotes ;) - I assume people agree as there are no downvotes at this point

Comment: @George  I would agree.  It looks like the ideas has support.  I've been mulling over a response to this for a few days and will probably write something up over the weekend.  You have a good idea.